# difference between ECDSA key and RSA key

Tags: ssh

what is difference between ECDSA key and   RSA key when we generate key for V2 of the ssh protocol?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not Unix-related and should be asked on crypto.stackexchange.com instead.

Elliptic curve cryptography works different from RSA. RSA is based on prime numbers, ECDSA can use any numbers. That means that a key of twice the size brings the security to the power of two with ECRSA (160 bit key => 2**80 key space, 320 bit key => 2**160 key space). With RSA the security increases more slowly. It becomes less and less effective to make long RSA keys more secure. In other words: You need more computing power per security with RSA (at least for long keys).